# Exact Equations $(x^2y^3-{1\over1+9x^2}){dx\over dy}+ x^3y^2=0$ Mistake!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Alright, I made a mistake on an exact equation differential equation but I don't see it.

We have the equation

> $$\left(x^2y^3-{1\over1+9x^2}\right){dx\over dy}+ x^3y^2=0$$

which I separated into $(x^2y^3-{1\over1+9x^2})dx+ x^3y^2dy$

I then integrated getting the result:

$\int x^2y^3-{1\over1+9x^2} dx = 1/3(x^3y^3) - 1/3tan^{-1}(3x)$

$\int x^3y^2 dy= {x^3y^3\over 3}$

We then get the final result:

$y=3/2(y^3x^3) - 1/3tan^{-1}(3x)$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Separating variables works only if all the $x$'s and all the $dx$'s are on one side, all the $y$'s and all the $dy$'s are on the other side.  So your method is wrong.

Comment: No I just separated the variables so that I could check the partial derivatives and integrate as you do in exact equations.

Comment: There are no partial derivatives. Neither x nor y are constants, so you can't factor them out of the integration.

Comment: I did the partial derivatives in my head just to make sure it was exact (it was) and then integrated.

Comment: Well, "I did a bunch of stuff in my head, can you explain what I did wrong?" really isn't how SE is supposed to work.

Comment: If you understand differential equations, which you clearly do not, you would have been able to tell what I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential
$$
\left(x^2y^3-\frac1{1+9x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x+x^3y^2\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
is exact. We can find the primitive by path integration. The exactness means that we can choose any path.

$$
\overbrace{\int_0^{x_0}\left(x^2y^3-\frac1{1+9x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x}^\text{letting $y=0$}+\overbrace{\int_0^{y_0}x^3y^2\,\mathrm{d}y}^\text{letting $x=x_0$}
=-\frac13\tan^{-1}(3x_0)+\frac13x_0^3y_0^3
$$
Thus, the primitive should be
$$
\frac13x^3y^3-\frac13\tan^{-1}(3x)+C
$$
Taking partials, this looks to be good.

Answer (score 0):

With $ydx+xdy=d(xy)$ you see
\begin{align}
x^2y^3dx+x^3y^2dy
&=\dfrac{1}{1+9x^2}dx \\
(xy)^2(ydx+xdy) 
&=\dfrac{1}{1+9x^2}dx \\
\dfrac13\times3(xy)^2d(xy)
&=\dfrac{1}{1+9x^2}dx \\
\dfrac13d(xy)^3
&=\dfrac{1}{1+9x^2}dx \\
\dfrac13\int d(xy)^3
&=\int\dfrac{1}{1+9x^2}dx \\
\color{blue}{(xy)^3}&\color{blue}{=\arctan3x+C}
\end{align}

Comment: You dropped a factor of $\frac13$ between lines 3 and 4.